# Ubuntu 12.04, 13.04: Cannot login to account returns to login screen

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, login, lightdm

### Question

In Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.04 (and probably 13.10) I made some changes to my graphics settings. After rebooting when I attempt to login to my account the screen flashes black the bounces me back to the login (lightdm) screen. My password is correct and I can log in on a guest account. Why by Richard Stallman's Scraggly Beard does this keep on happening!!

Answer (score 0):

I foolishly ran a GUI graphics tool as sudo! I was using a nvidia configuration tool and should have used `gksudo` instead of `sudo`. Here is how to undo the damage

1. press ctrl + shift + F2 to open a terminal
2. enter your username, then password
3. `cd ~` to get to the home directory
4. `ls -l -a` to see a list of all the hidden configuration files in the folder
5. If line containing the `.Xauthority` file shows 'root' in either the third or fourth column or both then continue with this guide. If not, you are having a bad problem and you  will not go to space today.

   A bad line would look like this,

   ```
   -rwxrwx---  1 root root       57 Jan  6 17:57 .Xauthority
   ```

   This means that root not $USER owns this file, you can remedy the situation by using `chown`
6. `sudo chown $USER:$USER .Xauthority` This changes the owner of the `.Xauthority` file from root to you. If you need more clarification of what this does, use `chown --help`
7. `ls -l -a` and check that your username (all spelled out, not "$USER") is where 'root' used to be.
8. Go back to the lightdm login screen by typing ctrl + shift + F7
9. Try logging in, did it work?
10. If not go back to the previous terminal by typing ctrl + shift + F2
11. look at the output of ls -l -a, make sure that the first column does **not** look like this

    ```
         -------rwx  1 root root       57 Jan  6 17:57 .Xauthority
    ```

    this means that the user and the group cannot access this file. to fix this, use the `chmod` command.

    sudo chmod ug+rwx .Xauthority

Hope this helps. I have managed to do this on three separate occasions so I hope this saves people some grief.

Comment: doesn't work for me.